# testing a regular expression for a third level slash?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to have a regular expression to test a URL that only goes to the second level / for example:

```
/brands/level2   -- this is a match


/brands/level2/level3 -- this is not a match
```

I have this regular expression that im using:

```
/brands/.+
```

but this also adds in level3 urls.

*note: level and level could be anything, im just using them here for illustrative purposes*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use a negative character class:

```
^/brands/[^/]+$
```

This will match any string that starts with `/brands/` and contains one or more characters *other than* `/`. The start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors ensure that no other characters are allowed before or after the matched substring.

Also, don't forget that you'll have to escape the first two `/` characters if used as regular expression literal (there's no need to escape the third because it's inside a character class):

```
var myRE = /^\/brands\/[^/]+$/;
```

Or just use the `RegExp` function:

```
var myRE = RegExp("^/brands/[^/]+$");
```

Comment: this is not working for i just tested it, its still adding level 3 urls

Comment: @user2681696 Did you try it with the anchors (`^` and `$`)?